# Induced current on secondary winding in transformer reinduce current in primary winding?

Tags: pcb, transformer, magnetic-flux

I am trying to understand what happens when PCB lines are magnetically coupled and form transformers and affect currents or distort voltages that is carried over them. I know if primary side in transformer is inducing current on the secondary side, induced current on secondary can reinduce current on primary side and if both sides are driven by voltage sources (like 2 independent signals carrying traces) what really happens?

Comment: Voltage is induced in the secondary due to current changing in the primary. Secondary current only flows when the secondary induced voltage is loaded. Maybe that might affect how you ask this question?

Comment: You are tying yourself in knots. `if primary side is inducing current on secondary` means that the primary is current driven, and the secondary is short-circuited. That contradicts your `if both sides are driven by voltage sources`. Usually we say a voltage driven primary induces a voltage on the secondary, and then the secondary load determines how much secondary current flows. However, on PCB traces, the coupling between primary and secondary is too weak to think 'transformer', it may be easier to think transmission lines or inductors

Comment: @Neil_UK Please consider the image here.(https://www.bitweenie.com/listings/mutual-inductance/). Let me repeat my problem in other words. I imagine 2 pcb traces parallel to each other. One trace carries data signal from source-A to destination-A, second trace also carries data from source-B to destination-B. Currents are changing in these traces and magnetic fields created by the trace currents create linkage. So we have a transformer and both primary and secondary sides are driven by data signals or voltages. Would not induced voltage on one side add to the data signal on the same line.

Comment: Yes it would. All I'm saying is that I think 'transformer' is not the best model to understand this weakly coupled configuration. Currents causing magnetic fields, and these changing magnetic fields creating a voltage in nearby conductors sounds just fine to me, for a qualitative understanding. If you want to go quantitative, then I think raw Biot Savart + Faraday's Induction law, or transmission lines, are two things to try before you try to force fit transformers into the situation.